# How to get list of paired Bluetooth headsets on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, headset, accessory

I'm trying to get the list of paired Bluetooth headset devices on my iPhone. I tried the External Accessory Framework as below:

```
[[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] registerForLocalNotifications];
NSArray *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];
```

but accessories array is always empty. Did I miss something? what is the right way of getting the list of attached Bluetooth headsets?

Assuming I could get the list of Bluetooth headsets, is there a way to redirect audio output to a certain Bluetooth headset?

according to the code below, there is no way to pick which device to send audio to:

```
UInt32 allowBluetoothInput = 1;
AudioSessionSetProperty(kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryEnableBluetoothInput,
                                sizeof (allowBluetoothInput), &allowBluetoothInput);
```

Thanks for your help,

Mehrdad

PS: I also tried [Apple's sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html) app which practices External Accessory Framework, no luck!

Comment: The external accessory framework is only for the 30 pin dock connector.

Comment: @JustSid According to Apple's documentation, External Accessory Framework supports external devices wirelessly connected via Bluetooth:

"The External Accessory framework provides support for communicating with external hardware connected to an iOS-based device through the 30-pin dock connector or wirelessly using Bluetooth."

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm trying to do the same thing with minimal success. Just want to help pair with a bluetooth headset via an app.

Answer (score 2):

Did you ever resolve this? I'm new to the External Accessory Framework, but from what I've found this framework only supports MFi compliant devices: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1657/_index.html

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this I used `AVAudioSeesion` from `AVFoundation.framework` and checked the available inputs with this line of code:

```
NSArray *availInputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
```

if you also need notifications when new device is connected or disconnected you can register observer to `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification` (you have to open setup new `AVAudioSession`)

please check my full answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29367963/1787109