# iOS how to discover bluetooth headset and its events

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

I am trying to discover "Bluetooth Headset" and get its events. I read the **"CoreBluetooth"** documentation and implemented sample code as below. It does not fire the delegate method '`didDiscoverPeripheral`'.

Is there any solution for this?

Code:

```
CBCentralManager *myCentralManager;
[myCentralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:nil];


-(void)centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{

    //following line prints CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn

    NSLog(@"state:%@", [self getCentralManagerState:central.state]);
}


//following method does not fire

-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like mentioned CoreBluetooth is for LE devices only,
so this is what I did to get the **events for BluetoothHFP** devices:
1. you need to open AVAudioSeesion:
link `AVFoundation.framework` to your project
2. for current available inputs:

```
NSArray *availInputs = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] availableInputs];
```

3. for notification on route change:
a. setup new `AVAudioSession`
b. register observer to `AVAudioSessionRouteChangeNotification`

```
- (BOOL)prepareAudioSession {

    // deactivate session
    BOOL success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error: nil];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"deactivationError");
    }

    // set audio session category AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord options AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"setCategoryError");
    }

    // activate audio session
    success = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error: nil];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"activationError");
    }

    return success;
}
```

and call this when you want to start listen to changes:

```
[self prepareAudioSession];

NSNotificationCenter *defaultCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[defaultCenter addObserver:self
                  selector:@selector(bluetoothAvailabilityDidChange:)
                      name:@"BluetoothConnectabilityChangedNotification"
                    object:nil];
```

4. if you want to get the callbacks while on background, you need to add Audio and AirPlay on target's capabilities:
   [image]

!! [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20898939/1787109) answer was helpful to me when got the solution

Answer (score 2):

[CoreBluetooth.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html) is for Bluetooth Low-Energy.
Bluetooth Low-Energy is not designed for passing sound (exit headset, speakers, etc.)
So my question is: Are your sure your headset is using Bluetooth Low-Energy?

I don't think so.

So, that's why the delegate method `centralManager:didDiscoverPeripheral:` isn't triggered.

If you want to get some events of the headset, like "user pressed next song", you can use the [Remote Control Events](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Remote-ControlEvents/Remote-ControlEvents.html).
As I suspect you may want to listen to "others events", I guess your headset is under MFI. So it may have its own protocol. For example, I worked on the iOS app for a Bluetooth HeadSet that had others functionalities, like calling a favorite number, etc. But, then, you'll need to use [ExternalAccessory.framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/ExternalAccessoryFrameworkReference/_index.html), and may have to reverse engineer the protocol.

Comment: I am trying to discover and trigger event of Samsung HM1100 bluetooth headset on iPhone 4S, iPad mini

Comment: On http://www.samsung.com/hk_en/consumer/mobile/mobile-phones/accessories/BHM1100UBECWDT?subsubtype=bluetooth-headset, its clearly indicated: `Bluetooth Version: 2.1+EDR`. So NO Bluetooth Low-Energy. I gave you the answer, and where to look (ExternalAccessory.framework, if maybe it has a custom protocol, but I doubt it, and RemoteControlEvents to get the events).

Comment: How come the devices are being displayed and can be connected to in the "Settings"page???

Comment: @Enkidu Refer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27049490/751026]  BLE devices are never visible in the Settings app until after a custom app has scanned and connected to them. Whereas 'legacy' BT devices are visible from the Settings app. With the exception of BLE devices that solicit for e.g. ANCS service connection.